Android Studio Emulator terminated
I formatted my computer 2 days ago and when I reinstalled Android Studio the emulator started doing this
In the log records it says:
2024-07-28 20:15:11,270 [  62082]   WARN - Emulator: Medium Phone API 30 - QEMU main loop exits abnormally with code 1
2024-07-28 20:15:11,277 [  62089]   WARN - Emulator: Medium Phone API 30 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\MEÃ‡.android\avd<build>.ini for reading.
2024-07-28 20:15:11,342 [  62154]   WARN - Emulator: Medium Phone API 30 - Failed to save 'C:\Users\MEÃ‡.android\avd..\avd\Medium_Phone_API_30.avd\emulator-user.ini'enter image description here
I turned on virtualization from bios.
I deleted Android Studio and installed it to the D folder.
I changed the username.
There is 170GB of free space in memory.

It might be related to your username, windows messed with it because of the accents.
Try to put your .android (and the env variables) on C:\
Then restart your PC
